# Inverse of rsync --copy-links?

Tags: rsync

Server, a directory with a bunch of symlinks in it pointing to things I want to sync:

```
/home/shish/tosync/video.mp4 -> /home/shish/videos/video.mp4
/home/shish/tosync/code.py -> /home/shish/src/code.py
/home/shish/tosync/foo.jpg -> /home/shish/photos/foo.jpg
```

Command:

```
rsync --copy-links server.com:/home/shish/tosync ~/tosync
```

Client, a directory with actual files in it:

```
/home/shish/tosync/video.mp4
/home/shish/tosync/code.py
/home/shish/tosync/foo.jpg
```

Now having modified the files locally, how do I upload them to the server, while keeping the remote symlinks (ie, modifying the various files scattered all round the remote filesystem)? All my attempts so far just overwrite the symlinks :(

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that what you want is not possible, at least not with rsync.